# I encountered a problem while parseing 2 dimensional array. - Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I encountered a problem while parsing 2 dimensional array in nuxt.js

It's okay when I first render, but when I refresh, I have a problem
like 'Cannot read property '1' of undefined'

To console.log, even if refresh, is fine

I tried cards[0]."1", cards."1". but it is error.

```
      if (response.results) {
        this.cards.push(response.results);
        console.log(this.cards[0][4]) // It's on the console.
```

in template

{{cards[0][1]}}

is error

Comment: you gave us very little to work with here.. can you provide more info? definitely cards[0]."1" or cards."1" will give you an error, that's not the correct syntax, but cards[0][1] should give you the correct result given the cards array is correct. ex var cards =[[1,2]]; console.log(cards[0][1]); //should give you 2

Comment: This is what my array looks like. [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: Oh, I added 'card[0]!=null' condition to the template, and the error disappeared!